# Vuejs 2 v-html not firing anchor events

Tags: vuejs2, jwplayer, innerhtml, vtt

I am creating an application using JW Player and Vuejs. I need to display vtt file reminiscent (https://www.ted.com/talks/julio_gil_future_tech_will_give_you_the_benefits_of_city_life_anywhere/transcript) where user can click and move to particular section of video. I can get the vtt file and display them using 'v-html' property which helps to render the transcript with line feed and formatting. What I'm stuck is anchor tags are not accepting '@click' event as its being rendered as HTML. Is there a way i can fire vuejs evetns

```
 <div v-show="viewTranscript" class="boxes"
                                     :class="{'animated fadeIn': viewTranscript, 'animated fadeOut': !viewTranscript}"
                                     >
                                    <!--<pre><a @click="videoPosition('00:30')">00:30</a>-->
                                    <pre>
                                        <component v-bind:is="vttCustomComponent"/>
                                        <!--<transcriptvtt :vttFileContent="captionTrack">Loading Transcript</transcriptvtt>-->
                                    </pre>
                                </div>
```

I tried using dynamic components as well but no luck so far. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change `@click` to `@click.native`

reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

---

**Update**

I think I understand now, the issues is that your browser is following the anchor `<a>`. Vue has modifiers to prevent default actions. You can read about it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

### TL;DR;

`<a @click.stop="myEvent">`

Comment: That's one way to do it. But situation is, vtt file is initially stored on database, with a bit of formatting, and decorated with anchor tags (@click event, taking time as parameter) which are supposed to take video on specific position.  Now when they are rendered as v-html, formatting and anchor tags are there but they don't fire (since they are rendered as html).

Comment: updated answer,  you can also use multiple modifiers, such as `v-on.stop.prevent.native="action">`